# Replacing values in a df with values from another df

Tags: pandas, dictionary, replace, lookup

I have a data table `df1` that looks like this (result of a `df.groupby('id').agg(lambda x: x.tolist())`):

```
df1:

id   people     
51   [125, 126, 127, 128, 129]
52   [302, 303, 128]
53   [312]
```

In another dataframe `df2`, I have mapped names and gender, according to a unique `pid`. The list entries in `df1.people` are in fact those `pid` items:

```
df2:

pid    name           gender
100    Jack Lumber    m
125    Holly Polly    f
126    Jeremy Owens   m
127    Ron Bronco     m
128    Natalia Berg   f
129    Robyn Hill     f
300    Crusty Clown   m
302    Danny McKenny  m
303    Tara Hill      f
312    Glenn Dalough  m
400    Fryda Beans    f
```

Now I like to replace or map the respective pid with the `gender` field from `df2` and hereby create following desired output, including a list count:

```
Outcome:
id   gender            count_m  count_f  
51   [f, m, m, f, f]   2        3
52   [m, f, f]         1        2
52   [m]               1        0
```

What's the best approach to create this table?

**Solution:**

```
from collections import Counter
d = dict(df2.drop('name', 1).values)
m = df1.assign(gender=df1.name.apply(lambda x: [d.get(i) for i in x])).drop('people', 1)
n = pd.DataFrame([Counter(x) for x in m.gender], index=m.index).fillna(0).add_prefix('count_')
final = m.join(n)
```

Comment: Pandas '0.24.2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dict.get()` to get the corresponding dictionary values, then create a dataframe by exploding the dataframe and apply `crosstab` and then merge:

```
d=dict(df2.drop('name',1).values)
m=df1.assign(gender=df1.people.apply(lambda x: [d.get(i) for i in x])).drop('people',1)
n=pd.DataFrame({'id':m.loc[m.index.repeat(m.gender.str.len()),'id'],
'gender':np.concatenate(m.gender)})
#for pandas .25.0 use: n=m.explode('gender')
```

---

```
final=m.merge(pd.crosstab(n.id,n.gender).add_prefix('count_'),left_on='id',right_index=True)
```

---

```
   id           gender  count_f  count_m
0  51  [f, m, m, f, f]        3        2
1  52        [m, f, f]        2        1
2  53              [m]        0        1
```

Comment: Thanks, getting very close! Only only issue left: The count does not seem to work appropriately. For instance: If I have a sequence like [female, female, male, female, female], it counts 1, 1 in both fields. I think it detects the gender presence correctly in a binary sense, it's just not the correct absolute count.

Comment: I just updated the example above so that it corresponds better with the true data structure.

Comment: Thank you! I also added a solution to the top that I found to work!

Comment: @Christopher I cant see it yet. :) I would be interested to know if there is a better way

Comment: Now I added the script above with Counter()

Comment: @Christopher nice to know.